# How to use an OSGI bundle within a camel route?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-camel

I have problems using a OSGI-Service in a camel route. Read [tutorial-osgi-camel-part1](http://camel.apache.org/tutorial-osgi-camel-part1.html)
 but didn't get it to work.

The setup:

- bundle 1 defines a Service interface (separate bundle for interface because there can be several implementations of it)
- bundle 2 implements this interface
- bundle 3 should use bundle 2 that provides interface from bundle 1

In bundle 2 (the implementation) are the two xml files, one with

```
<osgi:service ref="invokeService">
    <osgi:interfaces>
        <value>invoker.Invoker</value>
    </osgi:interfaces>
</osgi:service>
```

and the other with

```
<bean id="invokeService" class="invokerImpl.InvokerImpl">
</bean>
```

Bundle 3 has a xml file with

```
 <osgi:reference id="invokeService" interface="invoker.Invoker"/>
```

in it. 
Bundle 3 and the CamelContext is started with

```
@Override
public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
    OsgiDefaultCamelContext camelContext = new OsgiDefaultCamelContext(bundleContext);
    camelContext.addRoutes(new ExampleRoute());
    camelContext.start();
}
```

In my route I want to use the Service (from bundle 2) with

```
.to("bean:invokeService")
```

Exception I get:

```
19:14:39.953  TRACE  o.a.camel.core.osgi.OsgiClassResolver:42       Resolve class invokeService
19:14:39.969  TRACE  o.a.camel.core.osgi.OsgiClassResolver:84       Cannot load class: invokeService using classloader: CamleOSGIExample_1.0.0.qualifier [254]. This exception be ignored.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: invokeService
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513) ~[na:na]
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429) ~[na:na]
(...)
```

and

```
org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: invokeService
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.RegistryBean.getBean(RegistryBean.java:68) ~[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:83) ~[camel-core-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
```

I'm using Equinox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also discussed here and with the solution:
http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Problems-using-a-osgi-bundle-in-a-camel-route-tp5728064.html